# Use !Task.IsCompleted to show user current progress in GUI

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a task that might take a while to complete.

I have tried a simple demo but it locks up the GUI thread for some reason. I thought the task would be asynchronous and the GUI would update whilst the task is running.

Is this possible with a Task?

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething());
        while (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            label1.Text += ".";
            if (label1.Text.Length == 5)
                label1.Text = ".";
        }
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

**UPDATE:** After Damien's answer I tried the below but the CPU ramped up

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething());
        }
        public delegate void dgUpdateLabel();

        private void UpdateLabel()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new dgUpdateLabel(UpdateLabel), new object[] { });
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text += ".";
                if (label1.Text.Length == 5)
                    label1.Text = ".";
            }
        }

        private void DoSomething()
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Sleep());
            while (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                UpdateLabel();
            }
        }

        private void Sleep()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
```

**UPDATE2:** I think the speed of trying to update the label is too fast for it to handle. If you put a Thread.Sleep(500) after the UpdateLabel method call it works as expected.

Comment: I second the Update2, but in a real scenario, you would simply call UpdateLabel() from within Sleep() in the appropriate places, e.g. after processing 10% of the input data or such

Comment: May I simply suggest that while this might work, what you should do is add a progress-bar somewhere, and have that one visible and running while your background task is running, so you don't have to hit the gui-thread a million times while your task is running?

Comment: True but I dont know how long it will take.

Comment: you can use a marquee style progress bar for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating according to our chat :) :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  Task worker = new Task(() => DoSomething());
  Task ui_updater = new Task(() => UpdateGui(CancellationToken token));
  worker.Start();
  updater.Start();
  // Worker task completed, cancel GUI updater.
  worker.ContinueWith(task => cts.Cancel());
}
private void DoSomething()
{
 // Do an awful lot of work here.
}
private void UpdateGui(CancellationToken token)
{ 
  while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
 {      
   UpdateLabel();
   Thread.Sleep(500);
 }
}
private void UpdateLabel()
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
   this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => UpdateLabel()), new object[] { });
  }
    else
    {
        label1.Text += ".";
        if (label1.Text.Length >= 5)
            label1.Text = ".";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you updating the label to indicate progress?

Comment: Well, what progress do you want to show the user? The Tick of a second, x of y items done, the temperature? In order to indicate progress, the progress itself has to be measured/counted. Or display a working state like a Marquee-Progressbar.

Comment: In my example I'm just updating the label with dots and then resetting it. I could just show a loading image and then hide it once complete but I dont see how ContinueWith helps me

Comment: This example starts a Task doing some background work while updating its progress / signaling that its still running  to the main GUI thread. Unlike your example doesn't it use a while-loop to check if the background is finished, it uses the built-in callback function of ContinueWith. Thats what you wanted to achieve, right :)?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. The task is executed and the ContinueWith allows  you to do something else after the first task as completed. In that case would a Wait not do it? The issue I have is that I want to show some GUI notification that the task is currently executing

Comment: In your DoSomething method I believe I would fire up a new task that would take time to complete. Whilst that is taking time I need to update the GUI

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5286/discussion-between-jon-and-alex)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return from the `button_Click` handler before the UI will update. Maybe look at running a timer instead, to perform the periodic updates.

At the moment, your UI thread is sitting running that tight `while (!task.IsCompleted)`, and probably using up all your CPU doing so.

---

To use a timer, you'd have to expose your `task` variable at a higher level (e.g. as a private field) rather than a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted [Alex's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8245674/2031316), which IMO had multiple errors (and was not runnable):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WinForm
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething());
      Task updatingLabel = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateLabelValidated(_cts));
      task.ContinueWith(_=> _cts.Cancel());
    }
    private void DoSomething()
    {
      Thread.Sleep(20000);
    }
    private void UpdateLabelValidated(CancellationTokenSource token)
    {
      while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        UpdateLabel();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
      }
    }
    private void UpdateLabel()
    {
      if (this.InvokeRequired)
      {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(UpdateLabel), new object[] { });
      }
      else
      {
        label1.Text += ".";
        if (label1.Text.Length > 5)
          label1.Text = ".";
      }
    }
  }
}
```